Any apps or ways to smoothly scroll with keyboard shortcuts?
I looked for ways to do so with the keyboard but none of them work the way I want them to. I could do FN Up Arrow and FN Down Arrow but those go up and down a "whole page" and that's too fast, I can't change how fast it goes. Its possible to make a Karabiner Elements config to scroll with shortcuts but they can't scroll smoothly (have scroll intertia, which is enabled in macOS Settings > Accessibility > Pointer Control > Trackpad Options > Use intertia when scrolling).
